# e-mail validation in Openerp?

Tags: validation, email, odoo

I want to validate email in openerp through widget. Is there any method or is there any solution. How to validate e-mail in openERP. Simply the entered email address is valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this..

```
def onchange_email(self, cr, uid, ids, email):
    if re.match("^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", email) != None:
        return True
    else:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Email'), _('Please enter a valid email address'))
```

In your view, you would define the field with the on_change event, as described in [the documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#on-change).

```
<field name="email" on_change="onchange_email(email)"/>
```

Comment: Hello , but i want from widget. Apply to all. any idea how to add in widget.

Comment: I added an example widget declaration, @PinakinNayi. Also a link to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Email validation can be done using regular expressions. Following is an eg. code.

```
import re

def validateEmail(email):

    if len(email) > 7:
        if re.match("^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", email) != None:
            return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: Hello,first thanks but i want validate from widget. so where to write above code.

Comment: you can use it in onchange function.

Comment: It would be nice to add the source you used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex for the email validation

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/
```